# Can I take a sex item in checked luggage?

Tags: luggage, prohibited-items, sex

Does the luggage scanner detect the outlines of an automatic sex machine? Is it okay to take it with me to a country such as Egypt?

Comment: It will be detected and the outline will most likely be shown when you go through security - assuming it's in your carry-on. However, whether or not it gets pulled out for inspection, that's another story.... Where are you flying from?

Comment: It won't be detected if it was hidden in the "correct" place.. although the way you walk might be suspicious..

Comment: _Caveat lector:_ Third-party edits since the question was posted have made the item in question sound a lot more dramatic than it did originally.

Comment: Slightly tangential but you may be interested, since you mention Egypt, in this BBC reporter and her trouble with taking tampons through Egypt security http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-40221010